# How do you find a fishing rod in Terraria for PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita, terraria-console

In the PS Vita version of Terraria I can not find a fishing rod.

How do I find one?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, [fishing is currently only implemented in the PC version of terraria](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fishing_Pole)

Answer (score 0):

The update to the console versions that took place earlier this month (12/15) included fishing. Fishing rods can be created at different crafting stations and with various crafting materials; For example the "Wood fishing rod" can be crafted from 8 wood at a work bench.